# How to send notification in background?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, notifications, intentservice

I use IntentService to get data from database. This is my code:

**GetDataService.java**

```
public class GetDataService extends IntentService {

    public GetDataService() {
        super("GetDataService");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Parameter parameter = new Parameter();
        String data = (new LandSlideHttpClient()).getDeviceData();

        try {
            parameter = JSONLandslideParser.getParameter(data);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Intent in = new Intent();
        in.setAction(DataReceiver.ACTION_RESP);
        in.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        in.putExtra("123", (Parcelable) parameter);
        sendBroadcast(in);

        long ct = System.currentTimeMillis();
        AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GetDataService.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
                getApplicationContext(), 0, i, 0);

        mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, ct + 10000, pendingIntent);
        stopSelf();
    }
}
```

**CurrentData.java**

```
public class CurrentDataService extends Fragment {

public CurrentDataService() {
    super();
}

private DataReceiver dataReceiver;

TextView id;
TextView temp;
TextView acc;
TextView moisture;
TextView battery;
TextView date;
TextView time;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.currentdata_layout,
            container, false);
    id = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.showID);
    temp = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.showTEMP);
    acc = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.showACC);
    moisture = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.showMoisture);
    battery = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.showBat);
    date = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.showDATE);
    time = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.showTIME);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(DataReceiver.ACTION_RESP);
    filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);

    dataReceiver = new DataReceiver();
    getActivity().registerReceiver(dataReceiver, filter);

    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), GetDataService.class);
    getActivity().startService(intent);
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    getActivity().unregisterReceiver(dataReceiver);
    super.onDestroy();
}

public class DataReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static final String ACTION_RESP = "getdatafromBroadcast";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Parameter result = (Parameter) intent.getParcelableExtra("123");

        id.setText(result.getId());
        temp.setText(" " + result.getTemp());// + "  °C");
        acc.setText(" " + result.getAcc());// + "  m/s2");
        moisture.setText(" " + result.getMoisture());// +// "  mps");
        battery.setText(" " + result.getBattery());// + "  %");
        date.setText(result.getDate());
        time.setText(result.getTime());
        if (Float.parseFloat(temp.getText().toString()) > 25) {
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                    getActivity()).setContentTitle("My notification")
                    .setContentText("Danger")
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());

            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getActivity()
                    .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
        }
    }

}
}
```

**I have two problems:**

1. I want when the value of `temp` greater than `25`, then create one notification notifies user in case app closed. But my code does not create notification.
2. I use navigation bar and have a second tab named `Current data` which shows current infomation. I use intentservice and Alarm manager but my `CurrentTab` just operate when my app show this tab, but if i move to another tab, `CurrentTab` dont show Toast ( I setting Toast show when `temp` > `25`). So, Is my intentservice wrong?

   If you know my problems, help me, please.

Comment: `if (Float.compare(result.getTemp(), 25f) >= 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all check whether your if condition is working or not.. Put a toast or print something.. 
If it works, put this code in it:

```
 NotificationManager mManager;    
mManager = (NotificationManager) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(this.getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

 //Put the name of the class where you want to go on clicking the notification.. I used MainActivity

       Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);

       Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"This is a test message!", System.currentTimeMillis());

       intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

       PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( this.getApplicationContext(),0, intent1,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
       notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
       notification.setLatestEventInfo(this.getApplicationContext(), "Notification", "This is a test message!", pendingNotificationIntent);

       mManager.notify(0, notification);
```

This code for notification will work, just make sure, your if condition is working

Comment: Thank you @Prakhar,
Your code is working, but it does not auto remove.